# Efficent way to select belongs_to model from another Model, in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models:

```
Contact -> has_many :messages
```

and

```
Message -> belongs_to :contact
```

I want to select the last 10 contacts (as array of object, not only ids) from my messages table

this is my attempt (and it works fine):

```
Contact.where(id: Message.pluck(:contact_id).uniq.last(10))
```

BUt is there another better or  rails way to do this?

**EDIT**
**I want to select the last 10 contacts from my messages table**

Comment: What is "the last 10 contacts"? Unless there's some other code you're not showing us, like a `default_scope`, your code is essentially just fetching "10 random contacts that have a message".

Comment: Sorry, I want to select the last 10 contacts from my messages table

Comment: @spickermann I want to load the 10 contacts which got a message recently (by the created_at of the message)

Answer (score 3):

I would do this in one database query.

```
Contact
  .distinct
  .joins(:messages)
  .order('messages.created_at DESC')
  .limit(10)
```

Comment: I've always had this doubt: At some point, does making two queries work better than  a join? Or perhaps, in some cases, an inner query instead of a join?
I do not mean to doubt this answer. I believe it is the perfect one for the question. But I was hoping you could clear that doubt.

Comment: It really depends on your database schema, the table sizes and the indexes in place. My rule of thumb is that one query is most of the time faster than two queries. But you are right: When both tables are huge and have millions of rows then it might be a bad idea to JOIN them. But as long as the OP was happy with `Message.pluck(:contact_id).uniq.last(10)` (what loads all ids records into memory and then runs a seconds query) IMO it is safe to assume that the OP is dealing with tables that are small enough for the JOIN solution.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. This was just an added question, not particularly pertaining to the current question alone.
Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: sorry my english is not good @spickermann, for you, JOIN is better for huge tables? In my case I have to select the 10 or 15 last contacts that have generate a message in db (thats to say from the last messages)  without repeat the contact (uniq)

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? Is there an unexpected result or an error message?

Comment: I mean: `JOIN` is better for small and midsize tables. `JOIN` is not a good idea for huge tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following query:

```
Contact.where(id: Message.distinct.order(created_at: :desc).limit(10).select(:id))
```

This would produce the following SQL:

```
"SELECT  DISTINCT \"messages\".\"id\" FROM \"messages\"   ORDER BY \"messages\".\"created_at\" DESC LIMIT 10"
```